# Read file and fetch particular lines how to

Tags: php

people

I have a problem I want to read from a file and use and fetch some parts of the file like below. This is whats inside the file but I want to fetch the names. This file is used by my server and if a player logs in the server then the list of names get bigger. But I have no clue how to do it.. and I really want to know how to do so.

I already tryed stuff myself by exploding the first characters but thats how far my knowledge reaches.

Already Big thanks for the one so kind to help me out.

```
Players online: NAME1, NAME2, NAME3, NAME4, NAME5, NAME6, ETC, ETC. Total: 4
```

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: Yes by exploding the players online etc but i have no clue on how to only use everything between Players online: and . total: 4

Comment: can you post your PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out :

```
$line = 'layers online: NAME1, NAME2, NAME3, NAME4, NAME5, NAME6, ETC, ETC. Total: 4';
$pattern = '/:(.*)[,.]/';

preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);
$names = explode(',', $matches[1]);

print_r($names);
```

Comment: No problem at all ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = 'Players online: Admin Wouter, Krachtpatser, Dark Warrior, Anneleen. Total: 4';
// or read from the players file:
//$s = file_get_contents('path_to_players_file');

$s = str_replace('Players online: ', '', $s);
$stringPlayers = substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, '. Total:'));

echo $stringPlayers; // displays: Admin Wouter, Krachtpatser, Dark Warrior, Anneleen

// now get the player names in an array:

$arrayPlayers = explode(',', $stringPlayers);
foreach ($arrayPlayers as $k => $name) {
    $arrayPlayers[$k] = trim($name);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayPlayers);
echo '</pre>';

/* Displays:
    Array
    (
        [0] => Admin Wouter
        [1] => Krachtpatser
        [2] => Dark Warrior
        [3] => Anneleen
    )
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the first occurance of the `:` character and the position of `Total:` using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) and then use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) to remove these unneeded parts from the string. You could then split the string on each `,` character to get an array of names. Notice that the names will contain spaces so we could use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) in conjunction with [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove these:

```
// get the contents of your file
$data = file_get_contents('file.txt');
// get position of first ':' character
$pos1 = strpos($data, ':');
// get position of 'Total:'
$pos2 = strrpos($data, 'Total:');
// remove these parts using `substr()`
$data = substr($data, $pos1+1, ($pos2 - 1) - $pos1);
// split the string on each ',' character
$array = explode(",", $data);
// remove any whitespaces from the start and end
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key) {
   $value = trim($value);
});
// array now contains
Array
(
  [0] => Admin Wouter
  [1] => Krachtpatser
  [2] => Dark Warrior
  [3] => Anneleen.
)
```

To make sure you don't have any trailing '.' after a name you could modify the `array_walk()` callback like this:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key) {
  // trim whitespaces
  $value = trim($value);
  // trim trailing '.' characters
  $value = rtrim($value, '.');
});
```